# How secure are official updates by UBUNTU's Update Management?

Tags: 20.04, updates, security, update-manager

Untill now I receive my updates on a regular basis through UBUNTU's official Update Management, as provided in the package.
Being aware of threats of malware of any kind I wonder if malificent people might be able to hack those routines and fake or malificently modify official UBUNTU updates.
Who could tell me more about those risks?

Best regards,
Pitor

Comment: I don't understand "Se main site"

Comment: Stack Exchange they host all the sites.

Comment: He is not talking about the site but about ubuntu updates :)

Comment: security.stackexchange.com will have some good info on this. Example: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10106/how-secure-is-the-apt-get-install-command-against-man-in-the-middle-attacks and secure-apt: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man8/apt-secure.8.html also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178816/how-secure-is-the-universe-repository

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind, I found the article and read its answer by Rook. It dates however from december 2011 and hacking practices seem to have been advancing a lot....
Peter Krauss's remark fro Nov. '20 about DNSSEC may contain valuable info but to me it is maybe too technical (I am just a superficial but daily user of Ubuntu and I do know near to nothing about what's happening beneath the hood). I try to understand your latest remark starting wit imperva.com but I  am afraid that I will not be able to understand it well enough.
Do you think I shoul try to improve security on this matter?

Comment: @Pitor The method used is still perfect and has been tweaked over time but the general idea is so solid it has not been broken (yet :) ). The minerva link is about something else so I removed it :D

Comment: Oooh, thanks, that is a great relief. Well, that means that I won't have to worry for now. And of course the developpements on the UBUNTU-side will continue as well so hopefully UBUNTU will stay ahead of malware, especially in the updating department. 
Thanks, Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they can compromise the gpg key(s) used by the Ubuntu repositories then they would have full control. Otherwise the gpg signed packages in the repositories are totally secure, apt checks the signatures before installing if there is none or it is not proper it refuses to install a package or from a repository without a key in the secure keyring on your machine. It is called a web of trust it goes from the developers who upload and must sign each and everything done with their personal keys to all the machines that process the packages. Everything is signed and checked along the way in the process.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered by Rinzwind:
@Pitor The method used is still perfect and has been tweaked over time but the general idea is so solid it has not been broken (yet :) ).:D – Rinzwind

I am satisfied with this conclusion as I am sure that developpements on the UBUNTU-side will continue as well, so hopefully UBUNTU will stay ahead of malware, especially in the updating department.